# What is the best way to collect and store event feedbacks?

Tags: civievent, civicrm-event

I am looking for a solution where I could collect feedback with an automated email after the event. I figured, I could use schedule reminder for the emailing part.

But stuck with the step of collecting feedback in a way which could show a visual graph of the feedback submitted, as well as keeping the feedback record within contact record with event details (at least title & date).

I could create a set of custom field for contact as a table. This would allow me to keep multiple record of events feedback. Then add the custom fields to a profile and add checksum link to the scheduled reminder mail. But I cant get the event name pre-selected within the profile/custom field.

Has anyone tried any sort of work on this or any workaround? Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use webform and on submission create a activity of type 'XYZ'.